# Classical guitar 5th string buzzing

Tags: guitar, classical-music

This is to ask that I have a classical guitar Yamaha C70. Whenever I play the A note on any of the frets the 5 string I.e. the A string starts to resonate and it's quite irritating. It takes around 7-8 seconds to calm down. This happens only with the A string, not any other string. The buzzing sound was mild earlier but after changing the A string to ProArte normal tension,the buzzing sound has increased considerably.
Can anyone please help me find an answer ?

Comment: started an answer but reading again I'm not sure what you are describing. Does the A string vibrate when you play any A note, or is there buzzing when you play any note on the A string?

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is a buzzing resonance of the open A string when you play any A, the first thing to check is your nut. Has the string slot worn down letting the string sit too low. The other options are the height of the saddle, and then the truss rod tension (if your guitar has one - some classicals do, most don't)

Strings should resonate when a matching note is played, but the buzzing tells you your clearance is too low.

Comment: Sometimes a buzz can be caused by the short end of a string touching the guitar top behind the bridge and rattling like a drum snare. It would pay to eliminate this source by making sure the  short ends of your guitar strings are tucked up and not contacting the guitar top.